# How does the JVM manage both class loaders and memory when loading and unloading groovy scripts?

Tags: java, groovy

When you run a groovy script from java (using `GroovyShell` or `GroovyScriptEngine` ),  java compiles and loads the groovy script. Is there a special `classloader` for this purpose?

If I have a loop that generates and loads groovy scripts is it possible that I will eventually get a memory exception?

Is it possible to remove the loaded groovy class from memory? Can you explain or provide some resources?